# How to check if the input is null using ngIf?

Tags: angular

I want to check if Comment is not null to show the div

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Unexpected closing tag "div".
>   It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag. For
>   more info see

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label>توضیحات</label>
      <textarea [(ngModel)]="name" style="direction: rtl; color: rgb(3, 0, 0);" class="form-control" formControlName="Comment"
        aria-label="With textarea"></textarea>
    </div>


    <div *ngIf="{{name}} == ''"></div>
      <app-upload style="width: inherit; float: inline-start; width: 100px;"
        (onUploadFinished)="uploadFinished($event)"></app-upload>
      <img src="http://localhost:54277/{{this.response.dbPath}}"  width="200px"
        height="200px">
    </div>
```

Comment: Remove `</div>` on line 6 in your code snippet

Comment: Your template is wrong, `<div *ngIf="{{name}} == ''"></div>` opens and closes a `div` and, at the end of the snippet, you close again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 problems

1- Remove the closing tag `</div>` on line `<div *ngIf="{{name}} == ''"></div>`

2- You cannot use double braces in `ngIf`. You need to use it like:

```
<div *ngIf="name === ''"></div>
```

3- You use `ngModel` with `formControl` in the textarea. It will throw a warning. You need to set `ngModelOptions` like following to silence that warning:

```
<textarea [(ngModel)]="name" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"  formControlName="Comment" /*Other attributes remain*/  ></textarea>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The error is caused by this line

```
<div *ngIf="{{name}} == ''"></div>
```

remove the closing tag `</div>`